# How to find the maximum value of VarC for VarA x VarB in R

Tags: r

This is my first post in this exchange and I am a beginner in R. So my apologies if I'm doing this wrong. I did not see a way to directly build on an earlier exchange.

Earlier, Xinting WANG, asked the following:

> Currently I have a problem as follows. In a dataset where multiple
>   observations for each subject exist, and I want to make a subset of
>   this dataset where only the maximum data for a record is selected. For
>   example, for a data set as below:
>
> ```
> ID <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3)
> Value <- c(2,3,5,2,5,8,17,3,5)
> Event <- c(1,1,2,1,2,1,2,2,2)
>
> group <- data.frame(Subject=ID, pt=Value, Event=Event)
> ```
>
> Subject 1, 2 and 3 have the biggest pt value of 5, 17 and 5
>   respectively. How could I first, find the biggest pt value for each
>   subject, and then, put this observation in another data frame? This
>   means that this subset would only have the biggest pt values for each
>   subject.
>
> Thank you.

---

Arun had a response that I liked for its simplicity:

> Here's a data.table solution:
>
> ```
> require(data.table) ## 1.9.2
>
> group <- as.data.table(group)
> ```
>
> If you want to keep all the entries corresponding to max values of pt
>   within each group:
>
> ```
> group[group[, .I[pt == max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1]
>
>    Subject pt Event
> 1:       1  5     2
> 2:       2 17     2
> 3:       3  5     2
> ```
>
> If you'd like just the first max value of pt:
>
> ```
> group[group[, .I[which.max(pt)], by=Subject]$V1]
>
>    Subject pt Event
> 1:       1  5     2
> 2:       2 17     2
> 3:       3  5     2
> ```
>
> In this case, it doesn't make a difference, as there aren't multiple
>   maximum values within any group in your data.

---

Finally, My question is:

Is there an equally simple modification of Arun's suggested code that would provide the maximum "pt" value for Subject x Event. For Xinting WANG's data, then, I would be seeking the following result:

```
   Subject pt Event
1:       1  3     1
2:       1  5     2
3:       2  8     1
4:       2 17     2
5:       3  5     2
```

Moreso: Assuming a third variable (Year), is there yet another simple modification? Also: I am not concerned about multiple equal maximums (as addressed by the second set of suggested code by Arun).

Comment: `setDT(group)[, .(pt = max(pt)), by = .(Subject, Event)]`

Comment: Wow, alistaire, another elegantly simply solution. Thank you!

Comment: Check out the data.table vignettes; they cover this kind of grouped aggregation thoroughly.

Comment: Thank you. Wasn't familiar with "vignettes". But I was able to find them quickly. It will help me self-solve some questions in the future, I'm sure. Thank you again.